# Pattern or ForAll statment in Assumptions

Tags: simplifying-expressions, pattern-matching, summation, assumptions, forall

I would like to simplify an expression like
$\sum _{i=1}^k \sqrt{a_i^2}$, with the condition $\forall _{i\in \mathbb{Z}_{>\, 0}}a_i\in \mathbb{R}_{>\, 0}$ and with $k$ being undefined, which should give the following result $\sum _{i=1}^k a_i$.

My best, yet unsuccessful, attempt was the following:

```
Refine[Sum[Sqrt[a[i]^2], {i, 1, k}], Element[a[__],PositiveReals]]
```

which doesn't seem to take into account the fact that $a_i$ is positive as the result obtained is $\sum _{i=1}^k |a_i|$ (with `Abs[a[i]]`).

I have read ([here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/79756/assumptions-with-patterns)) that assumptions will work with `Element` but not with inequalities, so maybe the `PositiveReal` assumption is split in `Element[a[__],Reals]` and `a[__]>0`, with the first statement working properly but the second doesn't?

Here is the code of other tries:

```
Refine[Sum[Sqrt[a[i]^2], {i, 1, k}], #] & /@ {Element[a[__], 
   PositiveReals], Element[a[__], Reals], a[__] > 0, 
  ForAll[i, PositiveIntegers, a[i] > 0]}
```

I have already looked at similar threads ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16329602/is-it-possible-to-use-patterns-in-assumptions),[2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14984/pattern-matching-in-subscripted-variables),[3](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15410/how-to-define-a-large-number-of-assumptions),[4](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/273665/18816)) but couldn't find any solution.

**EDIT**

The question here isn't about the specific function/sum, but rather the formulation of abstract assumptions with arbitrary number of elements.

Comment: you can also look at [how-to-treat-indexed-variables-as-reals-can-they-be-symbolized](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/131778/how-to-treat-indexed-variables-as-reals-can-they-be-symbolized) indexed variables always been tricky to work with using assumptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assumption `a[i] > 0` may be applied, but one problem not mentioned is that inspection of `Sum` is limited.   If we inactivate `Sum`, it seems to remove some or all of the restrictions and `a[i] > 0` can take effect:

```
Activate@
 Refine[Inactivate[Sum[Sqrt[a[i]^2], {i, 1, k}], Sum], 
  Element[_a, Reals] && a[i] > 0]
(*  Sum[a[i], {i, 1, k}]  *)
```

However, if the `Sum` is stored in a variable, you need to evaluate the variable in `Inactivate`:

```
s = Sum[Sqrt[a[i]^2], {i, 1, k}];
Activate@
 Refine[Inactivate[Evaluate@s, Sum], Element[_a, Reals] && a[i] > 0]
(*  Sum[a[i], {i, 1, k}]   *)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
rule = Power[Power[x__, k_Integer], Rational[1, k_Integer]] :> x

Sum[Sqrt[a[i]^2], {i, 1, k}] /. rule
```

gives $\sum _{i=1}^k a(i)$.

---

**EDIT**

It has been correctly pointed out that I am using an operation on structure like it is done with pencil and paper. A slightly better pattern where I divide powers.

```
rule3 = Power[Power[a[i], g_Integer], Rational[1, h_Integer]] :> 
  Power[a[i], g/h]
```

---

Using it with `Refine` is not necessary. Patterns work on structure as presented in the `FullForm` output for the expression.

If this doesn't work in the context of your application then please modify and rephrase the question to include more details.

Comment: How 'bout `Sum[Sqrt[a[i]^2], {i, 1, k}] // PowerExpand`?

Comment: Also `Sum[Sqrt[a[i]^4], {i, 1, k}] /. rule` returns `Sum[Sqrt[a[i]^4], {i, 1, k}]` instead of `Sum[Sa[i]^2, {i, 1, k}]`.

Comment: The question here is not about the specific example (given as a MWE), but more general about the assumptions phrasing for abstract formulations.

Comment: @MichaelE2: The result of  `Sum[Sqrt[a[i]^2], {i, 1, k}] // PowerExpand` is not true in general and this is written in the documentation.

Comment: I didn't know `PowerExpand` could work when `k` was undefined. I am wondering, how it made the assumption that each `a[i]` was an element of `PositiveReals`?

Comment: @Syed Docs: "PowerExpand also converts (a^b)^c to a^(b c), whatever the form of c is....The transformations made by PowerExpand are correct in general only if c is an integer or a and b are positive real numbers." In other words, `PowerExpand` just does it, and it's up to the user to apply it only when the assumptions are met. (The same applies to your `rule`.)